# Changing navigator media constraints dynamically

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to control different navigator media constraints using range sliders but I'm not able to apply constraints dynamically. Here's the code I've written:

```
camera.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(camStatus == 1){
    var constraints = {
      audio: false,
      video: {width: { min: 1280 },
              height: { min: 720 }},
              frameRate: { min: 32}
    };
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(stream => {
      camStatus = 0;
      const track = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
      //zoom is the id of the range slider
      zoom.addEventListener('input', () => {
        track.applyConstraints({zoom: `${zoom.value}`});
        console.log(constraints);
      })
      video.srcObject = stream;
      vidControls.style.display = "block";
    }).catch(console.error)
  } else{
    camStatus = 1;
    vidControls.style.display = "none";
    stopVideo();
  }
})
```

I'm new to using the navigator API so I still don't know some of the methods you can use. Am I using the wrong method?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What *precisely* is going wrong, and what are you expecting? For one thing, `frameRate` should be inside the `video` object, not outside of it.

Comment: @Mitya I want to change the value of the zoom constraint when I change the range slider. I tried to look for articles on it but couldn't find any relevant resources. Now that you pointed out that `frameRate` should be inside the `video` object, will the same code work if I write ```track.applyConstraints({video:{zoom:`${zoom.value}`}});```

Comment: Sure, if `zoom.value` is the value. Obviously you'll have to make a fresh request for access with the new constraints each time the slider value changes.

Comment: @Mitya I've tried various ways to apply the constraints but it keeps giving me an error. It says that it cannot convert to dictionary.